# What is the fastest way to compute all eigenvalues of a very big and sparse adjacency matrix in python?

Tags: python, performance, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I'm trying to figure out if there is a faster way to compute all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a very big and sparse adjacency matrix than using scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh
As far as I know, this methods only uses the sparseness and symmetry attributes of the matrix. An adjacency matrix is also binary, what makes me think there is a faster way to do it.

I created a random 1000x1000 sparse adjacency matrix, and compared between several methods on my x230 ubuntu 13.04 laptop:

- scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs:  0.65 seconds
- scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh: 0.44 seconds
- scipy.linalg.eig:          6.09 seconds
- scipy.linalg.eigh:         1.60 seconds

With the sparse eigs and eigsh, I set k, the number of the desired eigenvalues and eigenvectors, to be the rank of the matrix.

The problem starts with bigger matrices - on a 9000x9000 matrix, it took scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh 45 minutes!

Comment: scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh uses [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/). This question is more of a math than programming question, so you may get better answers by asking on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ whether you can do something more clever than ARPACK

Comment: Also, try a literature search via e.g. Google Scholar.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted to [scicomp](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7369/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-all-eigenvalues-of-a-very-big-and-sparse-adja).  I recommend that we handle it over there.